# PyOpenCL vs Python Multiprocessing?

Tags: python, opencl, hpc, pycuda, pyopencl

I've researched this topic quite a bit and can't seem to come to a conclusion.

So I know OpenCL can be used for parallel processing using both the GPU and CPU (in contrast to CUDA). Since I want to do parallel processing with GPU and CPU, would it be better to use Multiprocessing module from python + PyOpenCL/PyCUDA for parallel processing or just use PyOpenCL for both GPU and CPU parallel programming?

I'm pretty new to this but intuitively, I would imagine multiprocessing module from python to be the best possible way to do CPU parallel processing in Python.

Any help or direction would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you already got your answer, but take in mind GPUs are designed for floating point operations, and execute a complete python processes in it could slower than you may expect for a GPU.

Anyway, once you are new in parallell processing, you should start with multiprocessing module, once GPU programming, and OpenCL library itself, are diffcult to learn when you have no base.

You may take a look here https://philipwfowler.github.io/2015-01-13-oxford/intermediate/python/04-multiprocessing.html